# Python subprocess OSError

Tags: python, import, subprocess

I am absolutely new at Python.
Here is my issue

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('date')
```

Of course this is not a useful program, I am trying to create something less primitive, but this error holds me back.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1106, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]
```

Earlier I was using os.system(), result was the same except i got no error traceback.
I only want to call CMD and use it through python ...

When I add shell=True the python shell freezes

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('date',shell=True)
```

btw I am using python v3.3, OS Windows 7

Comment: Does `date` exist on Windows?

Comment: It works when I put it into Command prompt.

Comment: Is `data` in your `PATH`? If not, are you running the Python script form the same directory as `data`? Otherwise, you'll need to provide an absolute path to `data`.

Comment: I am sorry I need an explanation what you mean by **data**

Comment: @Tom you've since edited your post replacing `data` with `date`.

Comment: @Tom FWIW, I just ran `subprocess.call('date', shell=True)` on Windows 8.1, Python 2.7 with no problems.

Comment: @shanet Well I try to instal Python v2.x lets see if it helps

Comment: If that's not it, I'm afraid I can't help. I'm not a Python expert and am especially a stranger to Windows.

Comment: Same prob at v2.7.5 anyway it looks like OS problem, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, python is saying it cannot find the file called date. If you search on your drive you will not find it. 'date' is simply a dos command. This is why it works in your Dos command window.

If you really want to test python subprocess, try subprocess.call('notepad') and that should work because notepad is a valid executable that is in the windows path. Any thing that is not in the default path you must specify full path.